# Выведение числового шаблонного параметра

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Доброго времени суток

Почему шаблонный параметр 32 здесь не выводится?

```
#include <bitset>

template <int N>
void printBitset(std::bitset<N> bs)
{
}

int main()
{
    std::bitset<32> bs(63);
    printBitset(bs);
}
```

https://ideone.com/Bnu1kR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <unsigned int N>
```

https://ideone.com/bSkf9s

Comment: А, ну да, точно. P.S. проверил на студии, компилит нормально )

Comment: Судя по всему, правильнее [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).